# the word for something that should not work but does

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a word that means "theoretically should not make sense or work, but actually does"

It starts with an a or e.

Comment: There are two (and only two) ways to describe something that should not work in theory, but does work in practice: (a) a flawed theory; or (b) a miracle. But perhaps you meant a *paradox*.

Comment: Another guessing game. From the SWR tag info: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: I wonder if you are thinking of anomaly - an anomaly is some observation or known fact which cannot be explained by a theory and doesn't fit in with the theory. According to theory the anomaly shouldn't happen. .  Beginning with E there is empirical - something which works empirically doesn't  contradict a theory exactly, but it does not depend on theory.  Neither of these seems exactly what you describe but I wonder if one of them is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **[enigma](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enigma)**, which, according to Merriam-Webster, means:

> something hard to understand or explain

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enigma) gives another interpretation:

> a puzzling or inexplicable occurrence or situation